# Iterate through Tuple Cplex

Tags: tuples, cplex

I have a tuple:

```
`tuple Torder{
    string part;
    int period;
}
{Torder} order = {<i, h> | i in part, h in period};`
```

Then:

```
{string} operation = ...;
```

I'm trying to create a new tuple:

```
string step[k in operation] = k;

tuple Twip
{
    Torder order;
    string operation;
}

{Twip} status = {<<i, h>, o> | <i, h> in order, k in operation, o in 1.. step[k]};
```

But the code `o in 1.. step[k]` outputs

> operation is not integer

Answer (score 1):

This syntax should work fine:

```
tuple Torder{
    string part;
    int period;
}

range period=1..2;
{string} part={"A","B"};
{Torder} order = {<i, h> | i in part, h in period};

{string} operation = {"Y","Z"};

string step[k in operation] = k;

{string} steps=union (k in operation) {step[k]};

tuple Twip
{
    Torder order;
    string operation;
}

{Twip} status = {<<i, h>, o> | <i, h> in order, k in operation, o in steps: ord(steps,o) <= ord(operation,k)};

execute
{
status;
}
```